# Which Java file does Hadoop HDFS file splitting into Blocks

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs

As we all know when a text file from local is being copied into the HDFS, the file is being split into a fixed size 128 MB. For example, when I copy a 256 MB text file into HDFS, there will be 2 blocks (256/128) that contain the "splitted" file.

Can Someone please tell me which java/jar file in the **Hadoop 2.7.1** source code does the functionality of splitting the file into blocks and which java/jar file writes the blocks into the datanode's directory.

Help me trace this code.

I only found the one where they did the logical input splits for blocks which is found in the FileInputFormat.java and that is not what I need. I need the java file for the physical file being split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for writing data into DataNodes is present in 2 files:

- `DFSOutputStream.java` (package: `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs`)

  The data written by client is split into packets (typically of 64k size). When a packet of data is ready, the data gets enqueued into a Data Queue, which is picked up by the `DataStreamer`.
- `DataStreamer` (package: `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs`)

  It picks up the packets in the Data Queue and sends them to the Data Nodes in the pipeline (typically there are 3 Data Nodes in a data pipeline, because of replication factor of 3).

  It retrieves a new block ID and starts streaming the data to Data Nodes. When a block of data is written, it closes the current block and gets a new block for writing next set of packets.

  The code, where a new block is got, is below:

  ```
  // get new block from namenode.
  if (stage == BlockConstructionStage.PIPELINE_SETUP_CREATE) {
    if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOG.debug("Allocating new block");
    }
    setPipeline(nextBlockOutputStream());
    initDataStreaming();
  }
  ```

  The code, where the current block gets closed, is below:

  ```
  // Is this block full?
  if (one.isLastPacketInBlock()) {
    // wait for the close packet has been acked
    synchronized (dataQueue) {
      while (!shouldStop() && ackQueue.size() != 0) {
        dataQueue.wait(1000);// wait for acks to arrive from datanodes
      }
    }
    if (shouldStop()) {
      continue;
    }

    endBlock();
  }
  ```

  In the `endBlock()` method, again the stage is set to:

  ```
  stage = BlockConstructionStage.PIPELINE_SETUP_CREATE;
  ```

  which means, a new pipeline is created for writing next set of packets to a new Block.

**EDIT: How does the end of block is detected?**

As `DataStreamer` keeps appending data to a block, it updates the number of bytes written.

```
/**
  * increase bytes of current block by len.
  *
  * @param len how many bytes to increase to current block
  */
void incBytesCurBlock(long len) {
    this.bytesCurBlock += len;
}
```

It also keeps checking, if the number of bytes written is equal to the blocksize:

```
// If packet is full, enqueue it for transmission
//
if (currentPacket.getNumChunks() == currentPacket.getMaxChunks() ||
    getStreamer().getBytesCurBlock() == blockSize) {
  enqueueCurrentPacketFull();
}
```

In the statement above, following condition checks if the blocksize is reached:

```
getStreamer().getBytesCurBlock() == blockSize)
```

If the block boundary is encountered, then `endBlock()` method gets called:

```
/**
 * if encountering a block boundary, send an empty packet to
 * indicate the end of block and reset bytesCurBlock.
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
protected void endBlock() throws IOException {
    if (getStreamer().getBytesCurBlock() == blockSize) {
      setCurrentPacketToEmpty();
      enqueueCurrentPacket();
      getStreamer().setBytesCurBlock(0);
      lastFlushOffset = 0;
    }
}
```

This will ensure that, the current block gets closed and a new block is obtained from `Name Node` for writing the data.

The block size is determined by `dfs.blocksize` parameter in `hdfs-site.xml` file (it is set to 128 MB = 134217728 in my cluster):

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>134217728</value>
    <description>The default block size for new files, in bytes.
        You can use the following suffix (case insensitive): k(kilo),
        m(mega), g(giga), t(tera), p(peta), e(exa) to specify the
        size (such as 128k, 512m, 1g, etc.), Or provide complete size
        in bytes (such as 134217728 for 128 MB).
    </description>
</property>
```

Comment: Really great answer, but how does this if-statement if (one.isLastPacketInBlock()) { } gets the information of the maximum block size? What part of the code indicates the file to be split into 128 MB?

Comment: Perfect Answer! Just to confirm, the if-statement that calls enqueueCurrentPacketFull(); is in DFSOutputStream.java, right?

Comment: @Idris, Yes it is in `DFSOutputStream.java`. Both `DFSOutputStream` and `DataStreamer` work together to achieve this. One creates the packets, other streams the packets. Both work together to keep track of block boundaries and get a new block as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a jar/java file which does the function of splitting the file. It is the client daemon which does this task. when you load a file from local, client reads only 128MB first, it finds a place to store it by asking namenode and also it makes sure that the file is copied and replicated properly. Client at this stage doesnot know the real size of file unless its going to read all the blocks in the same fashion.

The FileInputFormat.java which you have mentioned is not used by hdfs when you want to store a file. it is used when you want to run any mapreduce task on that file. it has nothing to do with storage of file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But certainly shouldn't there be a code in the "client daemon task" (that you claim of) that atleast has an if-statement that continuously reads data from the file into a block until the file reaches a maximum size (128 MB).